# How do you do TDD in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, xcode, tdd, acceptance-testing

Are there any good unit testing and acceptance testing frameworks that can be applied to XCode projects? I'm accustomed to doing TDD in Ruby and Python but am new to Objective-C and XCode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is the built in Cocoa Unit Test Bundle not good enough? Chris Hanson did [a series of posts on Unit testing in XCode](http://chanson.livejournal.com/119097.html), and there's the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/index.html) as well..

Answer (score 0):

The popular [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) library uses [GHUnit](http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit).

The advantage of using Apple's stuff is that it will improve over time and will have better tool integration, but I'm not sure it's as easy to use currently.